# Create Kafka-Connect cluster with Docker Compose to be used by ksqlDB

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

What I essentially try to do is to have multiple Kafka Connect instances with Docker Compose. I want ksqlDB to use this cluster. For now, they all run on a single machine, but eventually I want to deploy this to a multi-node environment. My problem is that ksqlDB apparently can't find the Kafka Connect cluster. There is the `KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL`, which stands for the URL of a single Kafka Connect instance. Not providing this variable results in the default value, which is localhost:8083.

I found [this docker-compose file](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/multi-cluster-connect-and-ksql/docker-compose.yml), which I think does what I want to do: ksqlDB and multiple Kafka Connect instances. Unfortunately, it didn't help me that much, since it uses an old version of KSQL Server. Here is my docker-compose file:

```
---
version: '3'

services:

  ksqldb-server-connect-test:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.15.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server-connect-test
    container_name: ksqldb-server-connect-test
    #ports:
    #  - "8088:8088"
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID: "default_"
      KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8088
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: localhost:9092
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://localhost:8081
      #KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: http://localhost:8083
      
  ksqldb-cli-connect-test:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-cli:0.15.0
    container_name: ksqldb-cli-connect-test
    network_mode: "host"
    depends_on:
      - ksqldb-server-connect-test
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

  schema-registry-connect-test:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.0.1
    container_name: schema-registry-connect-test
    network_mode: "host"
    #ports:
    #  - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: localhost:9092
    restart: always
    
  kafka-connect-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.0.1
    container_name: kafka-connect-1
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "localhost:9092"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8082
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: kafka-connect-test
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect-configs-test
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect-offsets-test
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect-status-test
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://localhost:8081'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "localhost"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_PARTITIONS: "25"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_PARTITIONS: "5"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/data/connect-jars
    volumes:
      - $PWD/data/connect-jars/:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/jars/
      - $PWD/jmx:/usr/app/
      
  kafka-connect-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.0.1
    container_name: kafka-connect-2
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "localhost:9092"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8084
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: kafka-connect-test
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect-configs-test
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect-offsets-test
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect-status-test
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://localhost:8081'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "localhost"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_PARTITIONS: "25"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_PARTITIONS: "5"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/data/connect-jars
    volumes:
      - $PWD/data/connect-jars/:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/jars/
      - $PWD/jmx:/usr/app/
```

Note that I use `network_mode: "host"` because the Kafka cluster itself does not run in a Docker container, so this eases the communication to Kafka in my case.

Does anybody have an idea or a solution on how to get ksqlDB connected to a Kafka Connect cluster using only docker-compose?

Comment: Can you clarify if you are you wanting two connect workers within one Connect cluster? Or two separate Kafka Connect workers?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt what I need to achieve is fault tolerance. I thought of having e. g. two or three machines with one Connect instance each. For now (testing purposes), it's enough to have two Connect instances on one single machine. The main issue I'm facing is how to connect ksqlDB with > 1 Kafka Connect instances. The requirements are basically load balancing and, if one instance for whatever reason dies, the other instance can take over the additional load, until a new instance is started.

Comment: Last I checked, using `localhost:9092` / `localhost:8081` makes the containers connect to themselves, not services on the "host network" (or other containers like the registry), and I'm guessing that's part of the problem. Forgetting ksql, and since you've shown no logs, does the Connect container (or schema registry) actually start?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I've set network_mode ="host" in the docker-compose file, that makes the container connect to the host's localhost.

Comment: Assuming your host machine is Linux, maybe. Still doesn't answer my question - did other containers start okay and actually connect with the broker? Besides that, using `host.docker.internal:9092` **without** host networking mode would be easier to reproduce for those of us not running Linux

Comment: Yes, they connect to the broker. And yes, I use Linux. I described my particular use case.

Answer (score 1):

> what I need to achieve is fault tolerance.

OK, so what you need is >1 Kafka Connect worker, within a single Kafka Connect group. This is what you've got with your configuration of the same storage topics and `group.id`

So the question is how to get ksqlDB to connect to a cluster of Kafka Connect workers. Since Kafka Connect uses Kafka itself to hold configuration, it doesn't matter *which* worker it connects to. `ksql.connect.url` (and thus `KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL` environment variable in docker) is the correct way to do this, but it's not clear from the docs if you can specify multiple values.

If you can't then I'm guessing you'd need to stick a stateless load balancer in front of the workers and point ksqlDB at that.

Also, the hostname is going to be the name of the container (`kafka-connect-1` / `kafka-connect-2`), not `localhost`.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't specify multiple URL's in ksl.connect.url. If I do, connect to ksql-cli and run "show connectors;", it says "io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlServerException: org.apache.hc.client5.http.ClientProtocolException: Target host is not specified". I've already tried that, I should have told that in the first place. I'll look into the approach of a load balancer the next days. Thank you

Comment: Yeah I confirmed with one of the ksqlDB engineers - a load balancer is the way to go. Feel free to raise an enhancement request at https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/

Comment: If someone's interested or comes across this question having the same issue: most likely we'll go with the approach to have Kafka Connect in Embedded mode inside every ksqlDB instance, since one desirable requirement is to reduce the number of applications to manage.